# Como retornar output varchar de uma procedure no c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, stored-procedures

Erro que aparece:

> `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code`
>
> `Additional information: Error converting data type varchar to int.`

```
public static string CriarPessoa(string procedureName, 
                                 string tableName, 
                                 string nome, 
                                 double cpf)
{

       string returnStringOutput;

       SqlCommand sqlComando = ConexaoComParametro(procedureName);
      
       sqlComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome", nome));
       sqlComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cpf", cpf));
       sqlComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@outputmsg", DbType.String))
                                               .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

       SqlParameter outputmsg = sqlComando.Parameters.Add("@ouputmsg", DbType.String);
       outputmsg.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
       sqlComando.ExecuteNonQuery();
       returnStringOutput = (string)sqlComando.Parameters["@ouputmsg"].Value;    
       return returnStringOutput;

}
```

***Procedure:***

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_c_funcionario]

@operacao [char](1),
@nome [varchar](20),
@cpf [bigint],
@outputmsg [varchar](50) OUTPUT

AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Funcionario] WHERE [cpf]=@cpf)
BEGIN

SET @outputmsg = 'Lamento, mas esse CPF já existe'

END
ELSE
BEGIN


IF @operacao='c'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Funcionario] ([nome], [cpf])
    VALUES (@nome,@cpf)

END 

END
RETURN
GO
```

Comment: Qual é a linha do erro, no código `C#`?

Comment: @israel3D - O procedimento sp_c_funcionario tem 3 parâmetros de entrada: @ operacao, @ nome e @ cpf. Me parece que o primeiro parâmetro, @ operacao, não foi informado. Poderia verificar?

Comment: @israel3D - Na tabela Funcionario, como está declarada a coluna cpf? 
A mensagem de erro, retornada pelo SQL Server, é "Error converting data type varchar to int". No procedimento CriarPessoa, o parâmetro cpf não seria Int64?

Comment: Não há erro apontado no código, somente no retorno do banco @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Realmente @JoséDiz, faltou  a operação. Mas no código está certo, foi somente um erro de copy/paste na hora de publicar a pergunta. E o erro em si é que não retorna meu output. Todos os parametros chegam corretamente na procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grato pela ajuda de todos, mas consegui resolver o problema: Era justamente porque eu colocava "(new SqlParameter)" antes, na hora de passar o parâmetro output. Ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
public static string CriarPessoa(string procedureName, char operacao, string nome, double cpf)
    {


        //INSTANCIO O PARÂMETRO ANTES DE PASSAR
        SqlParameter outputmsg = new SqlParameter();
        outputmsg.ParameterName = "@outputmsg";
        outputmsg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        outputmsg.DbType = DbType.String;
        outputmsg.Size = 2000;

        string returnStringOutput;

        SqlCommand sqlComando = ConexaoComParametro(procedureName);//faz conexão
        sqlComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@operacao", operacao));
        sqlComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome", nome));
        sqlComando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cpf", cpf));
        sqlComando.Parameters.Add(outputmsg); //AGORA ESTÁ ASSIM, SEM O "(new SqlParameter) COMO NO EXEMPLO ACIMA DO CPF"

        sqlComando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        outputmsg = sqlComando.Parameters["@outputmsg"];

        returnStringOutput = outputmsg.Value.ToString();

        return returnStringOutput;

    }
```